# Missing _fragment - embedded controller

Tags: symfony, templates

I followed this article:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

I am getting these errors:

> InvalidArgumentException: Controller
>   "CompanyBundle:Default:displayTimeline" for URI "/_fragment" is not
>   callable
>
> Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering
>   of a template ("Controller "CompanyBundle:Default:displayTimeline" for
>   URI "/_fragment" is not callable.") in
>   CompanyBundle:Default:manage.html.twig at line 26.

I have added the following:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    fragments: { path: /_fragment }
```

What am I missing? The controller in the article looks like any other controller? I flushed cache and reloaded as well.

EDIT | With "action" added to controller method and template call.

My template code:

```
{{ render(controller('CompanyBundle:Default:displayTimelineAction')) }}
```

My Controller code:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function displayTimelineAction(Request $request)
    {
      $content = null;
      return $this->render('default/timeline.html.twig', $content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change displayTimeline to displayTimelineAction in your controller.

Comment: Negative. Same problem :(

Comment: The Action suffix gets added to the controller method.  Not the render function.  Maybe review the routing chapter to see how the mapping works.  Lot's of magic.

Comment: This was it - I answered the question below in more specifics - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Cerad was correct - more specifically the fix was to change the template:

```
{{ render(controller('CompanyBundle:Default:displayTimeline')) }}
```

And Controller to:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function displayTimelineAction(Request $request)
    {
      $content = array();
      return $this->render('CompanyBundle:Default:timeline.html.twig', $content);
    }
}
```